# Redirecting a twilio task to a new TwiML after task/reservation timeout

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Currently using Twilio TaskRouter to build a telephony call center to route the calls.

My target was:

1. When a task kept pending for a certain time(i.e: no workers are available for reservation), redirect it to voicemail
2. When a task is reserved but the the worker didn't response to it, redirect it to voicemail

My Current Implementation was:

1. Specify both task timeout and reservation timeout
2. When task timeout / reservation timeout callback is triggered, query the [Redirect Instruction](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/reservations#redirect) reservation api to redirect it to a TwiML of recording voicemail.

But the problem was:

1. When a task is in `pending` status, no reservation was created so that I could not access the reservation to perform a redirect
2. When a reservation is timed out, trying to perform a redirect would receive an execption from Twilio saying that the reservation was nolonger available for redirecting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's two issues here, as you've said at the end. You're either trying to move a reservation that doesn't exist or redirecting a reservation that isn't available to redirect.

I think you can achieve your goals by using the workflow instead.

First up, consider the task side of things. You give a task a timeout. When it does timeout the normal behaviour for a task is to move to the next queue that it matches in the workflow.

I'd suggest setting up a final queue that has one permanently available worker object (but not real person) in it. When you get an assignment callback for a reservation for a task in that queue then you can use the [redirect assignment](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/handling-assignment-callbacks#redirecting-call) to send the call to some TwiML that returns a `<Record>` to take a message. Your TwiML application can also call the REST API to accept the reservation.

That works for tasks that are never assigned from the initial queue to a worker.  For the reservation timeout side of things, consider this.

When a reservation times out, the task goes back into its original queue for assignment again. The task remains under the same original timeout that we defined for it above, so will eventually move to our voicemail queue when the task itself times out. This has the same effect for the caller, as they never know when a reservation is assigned as they'll just be experiencing the wait music in the queue they are in.

Does that make sense at all?

Comment: Hi philnash, thanks for this solution. Just a question: how to create a "permanently available worker"? As soon as the reservation is created, either the worker becomes "reserved" (if the reservation isn't automatically accepted) or "busy" (if the reservation is automatically accepted). How should I bring it back to an available state, in order for "him" to process the a new reservation? Thanks

Comment: You could try using a [multitasking worker](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/multitasking) for that, which can accept more than one reservation at a time. Also, you can set [the status of a worker back to an available status with the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/workers#code-update-a-worker).

Comment: Hey @philnash, that's what I did. I checked with the Event endpoint and, as soon as the reservation is created, I update the Worker status to Idle. Is that the right approach? Thanks, Marco

Comment: I cannot figure this out. I commented on this other post, please help! :) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044542/redirect-twilio-call-to-voicemail-if-all-workers-explicitly-rejected-the-reserva#comment87427808_46051494

Comment: @philnash I just want to note that AFAIK when a task timeouts - it gets canceled. What you want is for the reservation to time out, in which case it will go to the next queue in the workflow as you suggested. The reservation timeout is set through the workflow UI.

Comment: @philnash can you help me? it's not working for me, I have created a new queue with one worker(voicemail), so now I have two 
task queues, in the first I have one available worker that receives the call, then the call timeout but it's not reassigned to the next queue that I have the 'voicemail' worker.

Comment: @Petran Can you start a new question and share your workflow and queue configuration?