# Redirect Twilio call to voicemail if all Workers explicitly rejected the reservation

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm using Twilio Task Routing to route calls to available `Workers` with a custom app UI built using TaskRouting.js.

Let's say I have 2 Idle Workers and a call comes in.

1. UI shows a screen Accept or Reject on both workers' screens
2. Worker 1 hits reject
3. Worker 2 hits reject
4. At this point, the task apparently goes back into the task routing queue and steps 2 and 3 are repeated.

After **all** workers rejected a call, how do I redirect it to voicemail instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I would achieve this by adding a [new array attribute to your Task](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/tasks#task-attributes) to record the SIDs of the workers that rejected the task. Then, when a worker rejects the reservation, adding to that attribute on the task.

Then you can add to your [target expression](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/expression-syntax):

```
worker.sid NOT IN task.rejected_workers
```

Once the task fails that expression, move it to a new queue that has one idle worker that rather than accepting reservations, just redirects the call off to some TwiML to `<Record>` the voicemail.

Let me know if that helps at all.

**Edit**

Turned out that wasn't exactly the right way to achieve this as, even if the target worker expression doesn't match any workers the Task will wait until there's a timeout at the filter level they have got to. The way I've described is really useful if you want to ensure that the call isn't directed to the same worker twice.

So, instead I recommend you still keep the list of workers that have rejected the task and each time there is another rejection, evaluate the workers in the queue and whether your Task's attribute now covers all the workers, ie it has been rejected by everyone. If so, set another attribute, something like `"totallyRejected": true`. Then, add to your original filter expression:

`totallyRejected == false`

Then, when a task has been totally rejected it will fail the expression and go on to the next filter.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Does the target expression go in the Workflow that assigns the Task to a TaskQueue? Or does it go in the Target Workers section of a TaskQueue?

Comment: Apologies, I was not quite right. Please see my edit above.

Comment: "now covers all the workers" – how does a single worker know the set of all workers?

Comment: The worker wouldn't know, you'd have to query the API.

Comment: The TaskQueue expression syntax documented here https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/taskqueues#target-workers only describes referencing attributes of a worker, not the task. I still don't see where I would use your example expression, `worker.sid NOT IN task.rejected_workers`. Thanks.

Comment: That may be, but check out the [more complex routing example with target worker expressions here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/workflow-configuration#more-complex-routing-example-with-target-worker-expressions)!

Comment: @philnash I have figured out how to send caller to my voicemail queue if original agent queue has no available agents. You said "rather than accepting reservations, just redirects the call off to some TwiML to <Record> the voicemail." How do I do that specifically? Where do I enter the url? Filter settings for VM queue? VM queue worker attribute? You also said to make "a new queue that has one idle worker". I did that. Voicemail queue, one idle worker with a filter that makes him only in VM queue. How do I redirect calls to that queue to URL to process TwiML?

Comment: Main Queue https://i.snag.gy/JMQiu3.jpg Voicemail Queue https://i.snag.gy/KypARl.jpg Filter Settings https://i.snag.gy/rjhawp.jpg

Comment: Linking other related question for future reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45386440/redirecting-a-twilio-task-to-a-new-twiml-after-task-reservation-timeout#comment87428577_45427339

Comment: What you need to do now is set up an assignment callback for your Voicemail Queue worker that responds with the [`redirect` instruction](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/handle-assignment-callbacks#redirecting-call).

Comment: @philnash I watched the requests made by the queues and it went in to an endless loop. When main call queue had no available workers, it send caller to voicemail queue and then it sent it back to main queue. Look at my photos posted. What do I need to change? Once the call is enqueued to my taskrouter workspace and enters the main queue, how does it leave and go to another URL?

Comment: here is an image - https://i.snag.gy/0XhbdJ.jpg - call comes in, no extension is dialed so it is enqueued to taskrouter. and my taskrouter images are posted above for the configs.

Comment: two more photos to paint the whole picture - https://i.snag.gy/M8z9CZ.jpg https://i.snag.gy/aU1Dzi.jpg

Comment: What happens in the assignment callback URL?

Comment: https://i.snag.gy/6i4sqU.jpg - https://i.snag.gy/cR8odj.jpg when caller is enqueued to taskrouter, the callback prompts agents to accept the call if they are IDLE.

Comment: Right, so all assignment callbacks go to that URL, so when the assignment callback is for your voicemail worker you need to return a [`redirect` instruction](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/handle-assignment-callbacks#redirecting-call) to the TwiML that will handle the voicemail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170498/discussion-between-jesse-szypulski-and-philnash).