# Twilio implement a voicemail with javascript sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I am currently receiving a call with the use of dequeue command.

```
_onReservationCreated: (reservation) =>
reservation.dequeue(
  null
  null
  'record-from-answer'
  5
  'https://myurl/webhooks/twilio/completed'
  'completed'
  "client:#{reservation.workerName}"
  (error, r) =>
    if error
      console.log(error)
    else
      console.log(r)
)
```

I want to send the user to voicemail after the timeout.
on my rails code, I have the webhook which is successfully called.

```
def completed
message = 'We are currently not able to answer your call, please leave a message'
twiml = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new do |response|
  response.say(message: message)

  response.record

  response.hangup
end
render xml: twiml.to_xml
```

end

The above is not working, the webhook is been triggered but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You have the webhook URL set up as the `dequeueStatusCallbackUrl`. Status Callback Webhooks like this are asynchronous, so you can't affect the call by returning TwiML.

The parameters of the callback should include the `taskCallSid`, so you can use that to call the [TaskRouter REST API to update the task](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/task#update-a-task-resource), move it to a different workflow or get the [`CallSid` and redirect the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#update-a-call-resource) to an endpoint that does then set up the voicemail.

Comment: Thank you, I cannot redirect the call I am getting the following Twilio::REST::RestError ([HTTP 400] 21220 : Unable to update record Call is not in-progress. Cannot redirect. Is there a clear example how to build a voicemail with javascsript sdk and taskrouter?  @philnash

Comment: Oh, seems like your call is over after the timeout here. I've actually answered this before, [check out the details in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45427339/28376).